# Normalize CSS w/local Stylesheet does not appear correct

Tags: html, css, normalize-css

I have been doing web design for a little over a year now, but still have strange things happen on the front end sometimes.  I am creating a simple template for personal use using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Matt's Template</title>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/general.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <section class="container">
            <h1>Matt's Template</h1>

            </section>

        <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <!-- My Javscript -->
    </body>
</html>
```

If I view this code in my Chrome browser, it appears that the body is shifted about 15px down from the html tag.  However, my css explicitly tells the html and body tags to have no padding or margin. So why is there this space?? This has happened before and I am not really sure how I solved it. There must be some obvious answer.  Here is my css too.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width:960px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#E0E0E0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qfSZ5/

Comment: Oh you are correct! I am so dumb... haha, I was inspecting every other tag except the <h1>. I always forget how encapsulated elements can make the rest of the document appear modified. Create an answer so I can accept you.

Comment: To avoid issues like this, consider using a CSS reset ( http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ) to override default user agent stylesheet properties and thus produce more predictable CSS behavior.

Comment: I mean, I am using CSS Normalize, which I have heard is better than Reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `<h1>` still has its default margin, you have only taken off the  default `<body>` margin of 8px, but not the other elements which have default UA styles. You should look into using a [reset](http://cssreset.com) so you can 'start from scratch' for each element.

http://jsfiddle.net/qfSZ5/3/

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment +1 for the suggestions.

Comment: I deleted it :p Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
h1 {margin:0}
```

or

```
h1 {display:inline-block}
```

if you want to keep its margins inside the parent.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfSZ5/2/)

Comment: Of course! @Adrift also gave more of an explanation and the suggestion with using a restart sheet. I merely left the answer up for the alternative `inline-block` suggestion =)

Answer (score 1):

That's because h1 has a default margin assigned by the browser; that could be kinda messy.
Some people just do this in order to prevent default margins and padding:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And that literally means:

"Hi browser, please nullify all the defaults margins and padding on all the existing elements. Thanks!"